# jQuery effect will not repeat

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fadein, effects, fadeout

After I hover over an img once, the effect wears off. I want my effects to continue after the first hover infinitely.

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=6&cat=-4'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; update_post_caches($posts); ?>

<li class="show1">

<?php $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>

<a href="#" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="show"><?php echo$thumb; ?></a>

<div class="hide">

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<a class="view_project" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">View Project »</a>
</div>
</li>
```

and the Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('li.show1').children('.hide').hide();

    $('li.show1').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('a.show').fadeOut('slow')
        .end().children('.hide').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
    $(this).children('a.show').fadeIn('slow')
        .end().children('.hide').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with the code, in fact, it runs fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/LakhA/

you're saying you want the effect when hovering over in image, but there's no image in your code...

Comment: some initial comments: you're missing a `<ul>` tag and your hrefs have unintended spaces (e.g. `http://www.mauriciobowers.com/ post-6`); now on to the problem... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working just fine. I'm using FF 7.0.1. Maybe you are using a to old browser.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the suggestion. It appears to be a Google Chrome issue. I'll take a look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the :hover effects in the CSS code. By changing out the CSS for some more simplistic declarations, I was able to get a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/La9LM/).

Also, I don't think you need to hide/show the .show element at all; removing this did not change the behavior in any way.

So, here is what to do:

- remove all the :hover declarations related to .show/.hide
- remove the js fadeIn/fadeOut for .show?
- use display:none for .hide (see my fiddle) to keep it initially hidden

And you'll have a working fade! ;)